# What is the meaning of non-trivial QoS in Grid Computing?

Tags: grid

What is the meaning of non-trivial QoS in Grid Computing ?
can somebody explain me what does that meeans ?

Answer (score 0):

Trivial QoS parameters (basic prerequisites):

- error free (eg. no distortion)
- multicast is not broadcast
- packet reaches certain destination
- List item
- ...

Non trivial QoS parameters:

- delay
- jitter
- loss
- effort

For guaranteeing non trivial transmission properties you need to use DiffServ or IntServ.